# Firebase Admin SDK not initializing(Java)

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-admin

I am quite new to Java and I am currently trying to use the Firebase Admin SDK with my application.
I am using Eclipse with the Maven plugin.

I have included this dependency in my Maven pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
     <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
     <version>4.0.3</version> 
</dependency>
```

After that, I made a new application under src/main/java and I tried to initialize the SDK with the code below, as the official Google Document asked me to.

```
package com.vogella.maven.quickstart;

import com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions;

public class App  {

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
       /*Firebase SDKをinitializeするために*/
      FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder();
    } }
```

However, I am getting an error saying that I have to change the code to

```
Builder options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
```

Is the Google official document wrong?

Comment: Post the _actual_ text of the error message

Comment: Err...okay, but the error is in Japanese as I am using Eclipse in Japanese..

It says "options"の型をBuilderに変更します。

Meaning "change the options to Builder"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you didn't [copy the rest of the code](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize_the_sdk)

> ```
>  FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
>   .setServiceAccount(new FileInputStream("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json"))
>   .setDatabaseUrl("https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com/")
>   .build();
>
> FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
> ```

Your error is that obviously a `FirebaseOptions` class cannot be assigned to a `new FirebaseOptions.Builder()`.

You must `build()` the `Builder`

Comment: Oh god.. this was such a noob question. Thank you!